# Virtual keyboard for typing Latin with diacritics characters

Tags: python

I'm developing a notepad with virtual keyboard integration. The purpose is to provide a free tool to type the Latin letters with diacritics. I came this far, but due my limitation and lack of coding knowledge I think will need partners to improve the app.

I really appreciate your inputs and suggestions. Further collaboration is open. As a tribute, I will include you in the list of contributors to this application.

[image]

I found some problems:

1. Backspace jumps to the end of the whole text.
2. save & save as function seems not working well.
3. keyboard binding problems

More features will be added later.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext
import tkinter.messagebox
import webbrowser
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename, askopenfilename
from tkinter import ttk
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Citralekha 1.0 (Beta)")
#root.iconbitmap(r'keyboard.ico')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry()
file_path = ''

global selected
selected = False


# font setting
text_font = Font(
    size=12,
    family="Helvetica")


# button functions
 
def select(value):
    global text
    if value=="⌫":
        txt = TextArea.get(1.0,END)
        val = len(txt)
        TextArea.delete(1.0,END)
        TextArea.insert(1.0,txt[:val-2])    
    elif value == "↵":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT,"\n")
    elif value=="Spasi":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT," ")
    elif value == "⇥":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT,"    ")
    elif value =="⇧":
        caps_buttons = ['|', '‖','Ø','°','ᴗ','/','\\','(',')','[',']','§','-','—','=','+',
                        'A','Ā', 'Â','Å', 'B','C','D','Ḍ','E','É','Ә','Ê','⌫','1','2','3',
                        'F', 'G','H','Ḥ','I','Ī','Î','J','Ē','Ĕ','Ə̄','Ě','↵','4','5','6',
                        'K','Ḳ','L', 'Ḷ','L̥','M', 'Ṁ', 'Ṃ','N','Ṇ','Ṅ','Ŋ','⇥','7','8','9',
                        'O','Ö', 'P','Q','R','Ṛ','R̥','Ṙ','S','Ś','Ṣ','Ñ','⬆','0','{','}',
                        'T','Ṭ','U','Ū','Û','V','W','X','Y','Z','Ẓ','Ż','#','*','<', '>',
                        'Spasi','M̐','˜','’','‘','\'','"','.','·',';',':','!','?'
                        ]
        varrow = 2
        varcolumn = 0

        for button in caps_buttons:
            command = lambda x=button:select(x)
            if button !='Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button,width=2,bg='black',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black', relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=varrow,column=varcolumn)
            if button =='Spasi':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black', relief='raised',padx=62,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=8,columnspan=4)
            if button =='⌫':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=3,column=12)
            if button =='↵':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=4,column=12)
            if button =='⇥':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=5,column=12)
            if button =='⬆':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=6,column=12)
            varcolumn+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow==2:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==3:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==4:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==5:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==6:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==7:
                varcolumn=3
                varrow+=1
                
    elif value =="⬆":
        varrow = 2
        varcolumn = 0

        for button in buttons:
            command = lambda x=button:select(x)
            if button !='Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button,width=2,bg='black',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black', relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=varrow,column=varcolumn)
            if button =='Spasi':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black', relief='raised',padx=62,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=8,columnspan=4)
            if button =='⌫':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=3,column=12)
            if button =='↵':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=4,column=12)
            if button =='⇥':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=5,column=12)
            if button =='⇧':
                Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
                    relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=6,column=12)
    
            varcolumn+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow==2:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==3:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==4:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==5:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==6:
                varcolumn=0
                varrow+=1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==7:
                varcolumn=3
                varrow+=1
    
    else:
        TextArea.insert(INSERT,value)
        
        

# Menu bar fungtions 'berkas' (file)
def set_file_path(path):
    global file_path
    file_path = path
  
def open_file(e):
    path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        code = file.read()
        TextArea.delete('1.0', END)
        TextArea.insert('1.0', code)
#        set_file_path(path)

def save_as():
    path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        code = TextArea.get('1.0', END) 
        file.write(code)
        set_file_path(path)

def save_file(e):
    if file_path == 'path':
        path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    else:
        path = file_path
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        code = TextArea.get('1.0', END) 
        file.write(code)
        set_file_path(path)
        
def endProgram():
    root.destroy()
        
## Edit bar functions (sunting)
        
def cut_text(e):
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()
    else:
        if TextArea.selection_get():
            selected = TextArea.selection_get()
            TextArea.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")
            root.clipboard_clear()
            root.clipboard_append(selected)

def copy_text(e):
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()
        
    if TextArea.selection_get():
        selected = TextArea.selection_get()
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(selected)
        
def paste_text(e):
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()
    else:
        if selected:
            position = TextArea.index(INSERT)
            TextArea.insert(position, selected)

def clear_text():
    TextArea.delete('1.0', END)

def select_all_text(event=None):
    TextArea.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
    return "break"

def find_text(event=None):
    search_toplevel = Toplevel(root)
    search_toplevel.title('Pencarian')
    search_toplevel.transient(root)

    Label(search_toplevel, text="Teks:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')

    search_entry_widget = Entry(
        search_toplevel, width=25)
    search_entry_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='we')
    search_entry_widget.focus_set()
    ignore_case_value = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(search_toplevel, text='Abaikan huruf kapital', variable=ignore_case_value).grid(
        row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2)
    Button(search_toplevel, text="Cari", underline=0,
           command=lambda: search_output(
               search_entry_widget.get(), ignore_case_value.get(),
               TextArea, search_toplevel, search_entry_widget)
           ).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e' + 'w', padx=2, pady=2)

    def close_search_window():
        TextArea.tag_remove('match', '1.0', END)
        search_toplevel.destroy()
    search_toplevel.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close_search_window)
    return "break"


def search_output(needle, if_ignore_case, TextArea,
                  search_toplevel, search_box):
    TextArea.tag_remove('sesuai', '1.0', END)
    ditemukan = 0
    if needle:
        start_pos = '1.0'
        while True:
            start_pos = TextArea.search(needle, start_pos,
                                            nocase=if_ignore_case, stopindex=END)
            if not start_pos:
                break
            end_pos = '{}+{}c'.format(start_pos, len(needle))
            TextArea.tag_add('sesuai', start_pos, end_pos)
            ditemukan += 1
            start_pos = end_pos
        TextArea.tag_config(
            'sesuai', foreground='red', background='yellow')
    search_box.focus_set()
    search_toplevel.title('{} ditemukan'.format(ditemukan))


def open_guide():
    webbrowser.open('https://kairaga.com/keyboard/citralekha',new=1)

#def open_angket():
#    webbrowser.open('https://kairaga.com/keyboard/citralekha/masukan',new=2)
    
def about_window():
    about_window = Toplevel(root)
    about_window.geometry("450x180")
    about_window.title("Tentang Citralekha")
    about_window.resizable(False, False)
    lbl = Label(about_window, text="Citralekha 1.0 (Beta) \n\n Program keyboard visual ini dikembangkan untuk membantu pengetikan huruf Latin dengan diakritik dalam proses transliterasi naskah dan prasasti di Nusantara. \n\n (c) 2021 Ilham Nurwansah \n\n GNU General Public License v3.0 ", wraplength=400, justify="center")
    lbl.pack()
    
def supported_convention():
    convention_window = Toplevel(root)
    convention_window.geometry("400x300")
    convention_window.title("Tentang Citralekha")
    convention_window.resizable(False, False)
    lbl = Label(convention_window, text="Keyboard ini mendukung sistem transliterasi berikut: \n \nInternational Alphabet of Sanskrit Transliteration (IAST) \nOld Javanese - English Dictionary \nDHARMA \nJavanese General System of Transliteration (JGST) \nPanduan transliterasi Arab-Latin Kementerian Agama RI \n\nSistem transkripsi: \nBahasa Sunda (Palangeran Éjahan Basa Sunda) \nBahasa Jawa (PUJL) \nBahasa Aceh", wraplength=370, justify="left")
    lbl.pack()


# Root Widgets......

# Menu Bar
menu_bar = Menu(root)  

# File bars
file_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)  
# file.add_command(label='New File', command=new_file)  
file_bar.add_command(label='Buka', command=lambda: open_file(False), accelerator="Ctrl+o")  
file_bar.add_command(label='Simpan', command=lambda:save_file(False), accelerator="Ctrl+s")  
file_bar.add_command(label='Simpan sebagai', command=save_as)  
file_bar.add_separator()  
file_bar.add_command(label="Keluar", command=endProgram)  
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Berkas", menu=file_bar)  


# Edit Bars
edit_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)  
#edit_bar.add_command(label="Undo", command="")  
#edit_bar.add_command(label="Redo", command="")  
#edit_bar.add_separator()  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Potong", command=lambda: cut_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+x")  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Salin", command=lambda: copy_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+c")  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Tempel", command=lambda: paste_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+v")  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Pilih semua", command=lambda: select_all_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+a")
edit_bar.add_separator()  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Cari teks", command=lambda: find_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+f")
edit_bar.add_separator()  
edit_bar.add_command(label="Bersihkan teks", command=clear_text)  
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Sunting", menu=edit_bar)

# Help Bar 
help_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)  
help_bar.add_command(label="Dokumentasi", command=open_guide) 
help_bar.add_command(label="Sistem Transliterasi", command=supported_convention)  
#help_bar.add_command(label="[Beri Masukan]", command=open_angket)  
help_bar.add_command(label="Tentang", command=about_window)  
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Bantuan", menu=help_bar)


# Print bar
# print_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)  
# menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Print", menu=print_bar, command="")

# Text Frame

text_frame = Frame(root)
text_frame.grid(row=0,columnspan=16,padx=1, pady=1)

TextArea = Text(undo=True)
TextArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(text_frame, width=65,height=18, wrap=WORD,borderwidth=1,relief=RIDGE)
TextArea.configure(font=text_font)
TextArea.grid(row=0,columnspan=156)

# Button Frame

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=16, padx=1, pady=1)

buttons = ['|', '‖','Ø','°','ᴗ','/','\\','(',')','[',']','§','-','—','=','+',
'a','ā', 'â','å','b','c','d','ḍ','e','é','ә','ê','⌫','1','2','3',
'f', 'g','h','ḥ','i','ī','î','j','ē','ĕ','ə̄','ě','↵','4','5','6',
'k','ḳ','l', 'ḷ','l̥', 'm', 'ṁ', 'ṃ','n','ṇ','ṅ','ŋ','⇥','7','8','9',
'o','ö', 'p','q','r', 'ṛ','r̥', 'ṙ','s','ś','ṣ','ñ','⇧','0','{','}',
't','ṭ','u','ū','û','v','w','x','y','z','ẓ','ż','#','*','<', '>',
'Spasi', 'm̐','˜', '’', '‘', '\'', '"','.' ,'·',';',':','!','?']
varrow = 2
varcolumn = 0

# Button functions
for button in buttons:
    command = lambda x=button:select(x)
    if button !='Spasi':
        Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button,width=2,bg='black',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=varrow,column=varcolumn)
    if button =='Spasi':
        Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=62,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=8,columnspan=4)
    if button =='⌫':
        Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=3,column=12)
    if button =='↵':
        Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=4,column=12)
    if button =='⇥':
        Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=5,column=12)
    if button =='⇧':
        Button(button_frame,text=button,width=2,bg='brown',fg='white',activebackground="white",activeforeground='black',
            relief='raised',padx=4,pady=2,bd=4,command=command).grid(row=6,column=12)
    
    
    varcolumn+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow==2:
        varcolumn=0
        varrow+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==3:
        varcolumn=0
        varrow+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==4:
        varcolumn=0
        varrow+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==5:
        varcolumn=0
        varrow+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==6:
        varcolumn=0
        varrow+=1
    if varcolumn > 15 and varrow ==7:
        varcolumn=3
        varrow+=1


# Keyboard Shortcut functions (Bindings)

root.bind('<Control-Key-x>', cut_text)
root.bind('<Control-Key-c>', copy_text)
root.bind('<Control-Key-v>', paste_text)
root.bind('<Control-Key-a>', select_all_text)
root.bind('<Control-Key-f>', find_text)
root.bind('<Control-Key-o>', open_file)
root.bind('<Control-Key-s>', save_file)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

I also put the code on Github: https://github.com/Ilhamkang/Citralekha-visualKeyboard

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is already a fairly large program. Before expanding it further you're going to want to go back and clean up a collection of minor and major things:

This program is written for a specific locale. It would be a good idea to be explicit about this locale:

```
from locale import setlocale, LC_ALL

indonesian_bcf47 = 'id_ID'
setlocale(LC_ALL, (indonesian_bcf47, 'UTF-8'))
```

As is very typical for beginner Python UI programs, this relies too much on global state and global control references, and has too much global code. Side-effects include higher difficulty of unit testing, namespace pollution, etc. There are various solutions, the easiest typically being to move to a class system.

Consider adding PEP484 type hints, i.e.

```
def find_text(event: Optional[Event] = None) -> str:
```

`TextArea` is not a good name for a variable and should instead be `text_area`.

`open_file` has a bug - it doesn't notice when the user presses 'cancel', and crashes when the path is then an empty string.

`endProgram` should be `end_program` by PEP8.

Your find code has a bug - when you find a match and the editor string is highlighted, that highlighting seems to be permanent and the user can add substrings within the highlighted area that will also be highlighted. A typical design would un-highlight the substring as soon as it's edited and no longer matches.

I find

```
    Checkbutton(search_toplevel, text='Abaikan huruf kapital', variable=ignore_case_value).grid(
        row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2)
```

to be more legible formatted as

```
    Checkbutton(
        search_toplevel, text='Abaikan huruf kapital', variable=ignore_case_value,
    ).grid(
        row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2
    )
```

For the most part you've been very good at keeping your locale-specific content in strings, and keeping your code in English; but there's at least one miss (ditemukan).

`global text` seems to be dead code since that variable doesn't exist.

A light refactor accommodating some of the above - but not going far enough to eliminate global references - is:

```
from locale import setlocale, LC_ALL
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import webbrowser
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename, askopenfilename
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from typing import Optional

root = Tk()
file_path = ''

global selected
selected = False

# font setting
text_font = Font(size=12, family="Helvetica")


# button functions

def select(value: str) -> None:
    if value == "⌫":
        txt = TextArea.get(1.0, END)
        val = len(txt)
        TextArea.delete(1.0, END)
        TextArea.insert(1.0, txt[:val - 2])
    elif value == "↵":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    elif value == "Spasi":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT, " ")
    elif value == "⇥":
        TextArea.insert(INSERT, "    ")
    elif value == "⇧":
        caps_buttons = ['|', '‖', 'Ø', '°', 'ᴗ', '/', '\\', '(', ')', '[', ']', '§', '-', '—', '=', '+',
                        'A', 'Ā', 'Â', 'Å', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Ḍ', 'E', 'É', 'Ә', 'Ê', '⌫', '1', '2', '3',
                        'F', 'G', 'H', 'Ḥ', 'I', 'Ī', 'Î', 'J', 'Ē', 'Ĕ', 'Ə̄', 'Ě', '↵', '4', '5', '6',
                        'K', 'Ḳ', 'L', 'Ḷ', 'L̥', 'M', 'Ṁ', 'Ṃ', 'N', 'Ṇ', 'Ṅ', 'Ŋ', '⇥', '7', '8', '9',
                        'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'Ṛ', 'R̥', 'Ṙ', 'S', 'Ś', 'Ṣ', 'Ñ', '⬆', '0', '{', '}',
                        'T', 'Ṭ', 'U', 'Ū', 'Û', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ẓ', 'Ż', '#', '*', '<', '>',
                        'Spasi', 'M̐', '˜', '’', '‘', '\'', '"', '.', '·', ';', ':', '!', '?'
                        ]
        varrow = 2
        varcolumn = 0

        for button in caps_buttons:
            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button, width=2, bg='black', fg='white',
                       activebackground="white", activeforeground='black', relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4,
                       command=command).grid(row=varrow, column=varcolumn)
            if button == 'Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black', relief='raised', padx=62, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=8,
                                                                                                               columnspan=4)
            if button == '⌫':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=3, column=12)
            if button == '↵':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=4, column=12)
            if button == '⇥':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=5, column=12)
            if button == '⬆':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=6, column=12)
            varcolumn += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 2:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 3:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 4:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 5:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 6:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 7:
                varcolumn = 3
                varrow += 1

    elif value == "⬆":
        varrow = 2
        varcolumn = 0

        for button in buttons:
            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button, width=2, bg='black', fg='white',
                       activebackground="white", activeforeground='black', relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4,
                       command=command).grid(row=varrow, column=varcolumn)
            if button == 'Spasi':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black', relief='raised', padx=62, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=8,
                                                                                                               columnspan=4)
            if button == '⌫':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=3, column=12)
            if button == '↵':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=4, column=12)
            if button == '⇥':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=5, column=12)
            if button == '⇧':
                Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                       activeforeground='black',
                       relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=6, column=12)

            varcolumn += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 2:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 3:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 4:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 5:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 6:
                varcolumn = 0
                varrow += 1
            if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 7:
                varcolumn = 3
                varrow += 1

    else:
        TextArea.insert(INSERT, value)


# Menu bar functions 'berkas' (file)
def set_file_path(path) -> None:
    global file_path
    file_path = path


def open_file(e: bool) -> None:
    path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    if path:
        with open(path, 'r') as file:
            code = file.read()
            TextArea.delete('1.0', END)
            TextArea.insert('1.0', code)


def save_as() -> None:
    path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        code = TextArea.get('1.0', END)
        file.write(code)
        set_file_path(path)


def save_file(e: bool) -> None:
    if file_path == 'path':
        path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Berkas Teks', '*.txt')])
    else:
        path = file_path
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        code = TextArea.get('1.0', END)
        file.write(code)
        set_file_path(path)


def endProgram() -> None:
    root.destroy()


## Edit bar functions (sunting)

def cut_text(e: Event) -> None:
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()
    else:
        if TextArea.selection_get():
            selected = TextArea.selection_get()
            TextArea.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")
            root.clipboard_clear()
            root.clipboard_append(selected)


def copy_text(e: Event) -> None:
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()

    if TextArea.selection_get():
        selected = TextArea.selection_get()
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(selected)


def paste_text(e: Event) -> None:
    global selected
    if e:
        selected = root.clipboard_get()
    elif selected:
        position = TextArea.index(INSERT)
        TextArea.insert(position, selected)


def clear_text() -> None:
    TextArea.delete('1.0', END)


def select_all_text(event: Optional[Event] = None) -> str:
    TextArea.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
    return "break"


def find_text(event: Optional[Event] = None) -> str:
    search_toplevel = Toplevel(root)
    search_toplevel.title('Pencarian')
    search_toplevel.transient(root)

    Label(search_toplevel, text="Teks:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')

    search_entry_widget = Entry(
        search_toplevel, width=25)
    search_entry_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='we')
    search_entry_widget.focus_set()
    ignore_case_value = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(
        search_toplevel, text='Abaikan huruf kapital', variable=ignore_case_value,
    ).grid(
        row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2
    )
    Button(
        search_toplevel, text="Cari", underline=0,
        command=lambda: search_output(
            search_entry_widget.get(), ignore_case_value.get() == 1,
            TextArea, search_toplevel, search_entry_widget,
        )
    ).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e' + 'w', padx=2, pady=2)

    def close_search_window() -> None:
        TextArea.tag_remove('match', '1.0', END)
        search_toplevel.destroy()

    search_toplevel.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close_search_window)
    return "break"


def search_output(
    needle: str, if_ignore_case: bool, text_area: ScrolledText,
    search_toplevel: Toplevel, search_box: Entry,
) -> None:
    text_area.tag_remove('sesuai', '1.0', END)
    ditemukan = 0
    if needle:
        start_pos = '1.0'
        while True:
            start_pos = text_area.search(
                needle, start_pos, nocase=if_ignore_case, stopindex=END,
            )
            if not start_pos:
                break
            end_pos = '{}+{}c'.format(start_pos, len(needle))
            text_area.tag_add('sesuai', start_pos, end_pos)
            ditemukan += 1
            start_pos = end_pos
        text_area.tag_config(
            'sesuai', foreground='red', background='yellow')
    search_box.focus_set()
    search_toplevel.title('{} ditemukan'.format(ditemukan))


def open_guide() -> None:
    webbrowser.open('https://kairaga.com/keyboard/citralekha', new=1)


# def open_angket():
#    webbrowser.open('https://kairaga.com/keyboard/citralekha/masukan',new=2)

def about_window() -> None:
    about_window = Toplevel(root)
    about_window.geometry("450x180")
    about_window.title("Tentang Citralekha")
    about_window.resizable(False, False)
    lbl = Label(about_window,
                text="Citralekha 1.0 (Beta) \n\n Program keyboard visual ini dikembangkan untuk membantu pengetikan huruf Latin dengan diakritik dalam proses transliterasi naskah dan prasasti di Nusantara. \n\n (c) 2021 Ilham Nurwansah \n\n GNU General Public License v3.0 ",
                wraplength=400, justify="center")
    lbl.pack()


def supported_convention() -> None:
    convention_window = Toplevel(root)
    convention_window.geometry("400x300")
    convention_window.title("Tentang Citralekha")
    convention_window.resizable(False, False)
    lbl = Label(convention_window,
                text="Keyboard ini mendukung sistem transliterasi berikut: \n \nInternational Alphabet of Sanskrit Transliteration (IAST) \nOld Javanese - English Dictionary \nDHARMA \nJavanese General System of Transliteration (JGST) \nPanduan transliterasi Arab-Latin Kementerian Agama RI \n\nSistem transkripsi: \nBahasa Sunda (Palangeran Éjahan Basa Sunda) \nBahasa Jawa (PUJL) \nBahasa Aceh",
                wraplength=370, justify="left")
    lbl.pack()


menu_bar = Menu(root)
file_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
edit_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
help_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
text_frame = Frame(root)
TextArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(text_frame, width=65, height=18, wrap=WORD, borderwidth=1, relief=RIDGE)
button_frame = Frame(root)

buttons = ['|', '‖', 'Ø', '°', 'ᴗ', '/', '\\', '(', ')', '[', ']', '§', '-', '—', '=', '+',
           'a', 'ā', 'â', 'å', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ḍ', 'e', 'é', 'ә', 'ê', '⌫', '1', '2', '3',
           'f', 'g', 'h', 'ḥ', 'i', 'ī', 'î', 'j', 'ē', 'ĕ', 'ə̄', 'ě', '↵', '4', '5', '6',
           'k', 'ḳ', 'l', 'ḷ', 'l̥', 'm', 'ṁ', 'ṃ', 'n', 'ṇ', 'ṅ', 'ŋ', '⇥', '7', '8', '9',
           'o', 'ö', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'ṛ', 'r̥', 'ṙ', 's', 'ś', 'ṣ', 'ñ', '⇧', '0', '{', '}',
           't', 'ṭ', 'u', 'ū', 'û', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ẓ', 'ż', '#', '*', '<', '>',
           'Spasi', 'm̐', '˜', '’', '‘', '\'', '"', '.', '·', ';', ':', '!', '?']


def main() -> None:
    indonesian_bcf47 = 'id_ID'
    setlocale(LC_ALL, (indonesian_bcf47, 'UTF-8'))

    root.title("Citralekha 1.0 (Beta)")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.geometry()

    # file.add_command(label='New File', command=new_file)
    file_bar.add_command(label='Buka', command=lambda: open_file(False), accelerator="Ctrl+o")
    file_bar.add_command(label='Simpan', command=lambda: save_file(False), accelerator="Ctrl+s")
    file_bar.add_command(label='Simpan sebagai', command=save_as)
    file_bar.add_separator()
    file_bar.add_command(label="Keluar", command=endProgram)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Berkas", menu=file_bar)

    # edit_bar.add_command(label="Undo", command="")
    # edit_bar.add_command(label="Redo", command="")
    # edit_bar.add_separator()
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Potong", command=lambda: cut_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+x")
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Salin", command=lambda: copy_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+c")
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Tempel", command=lambda: paste_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+v")
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Pilih semua", command=lambda: select_all_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+a")
    edit_bar.add_separator()
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Cari teks", command=lambda: find_text(False), accelerator="Ctrl+f")
    edit_bar.add_separator()
    edit_bar.add_command(label="Bersihkan teks", command=clear_text)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Sunting", menu=edit_bar)

    help_bar.add_command(label="Dokumentasi", command=open_guide)
    help_bar.add_command(label="Sistem Transliterasi", command=supported_convention)
    # help_bar.add_command(label="[Beri Masukan]", command=open_angket)
    help_bar.add_command(label="Tentang", command=about_window)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Bantuan", menu=help_bar)

    # Print bar
    # print_bar = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
    # menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Print", menu=print_bar, command="")

    # Text Frame
    text_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=16, padx=1, pady=1)

    TextArea.configure(font=text_font)
    TextArea.grid(row=0, columnspan=156)

    # Button Frame
    button_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=16, padx=1, pady=1)

    varrow = 2
    varcolumn = 0

    # Button functions
    for button in buttons:
        command = lambda x=button: select(x)
        if button != 'Spasi':
            Button(button_frame, font=text_font, text=button, width=2, bg='black', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=varrow, column=varcolumn)
        if button == 'Spasi':
            Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=62, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=8, columnspan=4)
        if button == '⌫':
            Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=3, column=12)
        if button == '↵':
            Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=4, column=12)
        if button == '⇥':
            Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=5, column=12)
        if button == '⇧':
            Button(button_frame, text=button, width=2, bg='brown', fg='white', activebackground="white",
                   activeforeground='black',
                   relief='raised', padx=4, pady=2, bd=4, command=command).grid(row=6, column=12)

        varcolumn += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 2:
            varcolumn = 0
            varrow += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 3:
            varcolumn = 0
            varrow += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 4:
            varcolumn = 0
            varrow += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 5:
            varcolumn = 0
            varrow += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 6:
            varcolumn = 0
            varrow += 1
        if varcolumn > 15 and varrow == 7:
            varcolumn = 3
            varrow += 1

    # Keyboard Shortcut functions (Bindings)

    root.bind('<Control-Key-x>', cut_text)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-c>', copy_text)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-v>', paste_text)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-a>', select_all_text)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-f>', find_text)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-o>', open_file)
    root.bind('<Control-Key-s>', save_file)

    root.config(menu=menu_bar)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, Reinderien! This is helpful. I will try to tidy up the variable names and using class system.